# Create a new TFS Team Project and use existing source control folder

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I currently have a source control folder in TFS with all of my source code.
Is it possible to create a **new** team project and use the existing source control folder?

I have the option to create a new source control folder, create a new branch or not to create one at all. But is there a way of using an existing folder?

[Edit]
To clarify:
I have previously had a Team Project and Source Control folder called ProjectA and $/ProjectA. If I delete the Team Project but retain the Source control folder $/ProjectA and then later want to recreate a Team Project called ProjectA, with a new template say, can I reattach the existing source control folder $/ProjectA?

Sounds like I might not be able to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - I'm afraid that you must have a folder in source control for your Team Project.

Under the hood a few settings for the Team Project are actually stored in the version control system on the "$/TeamProject" folder, hence the dependency TFS has for a version control folder to match the Team Project name.

Can I ask why you wanted to create a new team project like this?  There might be another way to achieve what you want, or if not it would be valuable feedback for the Microsoft team anyway.